# Django Incorrect integer value: 'True' for column 'is_superuser' at row 1

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I've used [django-simple-history](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history/tree/master/simple_history) library to implement history tracking in one of my Django project and it worked fine until I started to make changes in my project to move it to Google Application Engine with Cloud SQL. Now, it seems to fail on the Boolean fields with the below warning:

```
Warning at /admin/
Incorrect integer value: 'True' for column 'is_superuser' at row 1
```

Below part of the code seems to be causing the issue in simple_history/models.py file, which breaks on creating history if there are any Boolean fields in the model:

```
def create_historical_record(self, instance, type):
        history_user = getattr(instance, '_history_user', None)
        manager = getattr(instance, self.manager_name)
        attrs = {}
        for field in instance._meta.fields:
            attrs[field.attname] = getattr(instance, field.attname)
        manager.create(history_type=type, history_user=history_user, **attrs)
```

This works find on my machine but breaks on google app engine. Please suggest.

**Update:** solved

The MySQLdb library was customized in my case. Boolean to integer conversion was removed in converter.py script by commenting the line "BooleanType: Bool2Str".

Answer (score 0):

As far i know Google cloud was supporting Django version 1.4, it could be reason, After Django 1.5 boolean fields changed to true/false instead of 0, 1.

I would suggest you to change your local django version to 1.4 and try.

Comment: I think this is not the case. Boolean fields was changed from integer to Bool values in Django 1.2, I tried changing the django version to 1.4 as well but that too didn't work.