# column "is_superuser" is of type integer but expression is of type boolean DJANGO Error

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, heroku-postgres

I could use some help.  My python 3.4 Django 1.7.4 site worked fine using sqlite.  Now I've moved it to Heroku which uses Postgres.  And when I try to create a user / password i get this error:

```
column "is_superuser" is of type integer but expression is of type boolean
LINE 1: ...15-02-08 19:23:26.965870+00:00', "is_superuser" = false, "us...
                                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

The last function call in the stack trace is:
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) ...
▶ Local vars
```

I don't have access to the base django code,  just the code on my app.  So any help getting this to work would be really helpful.

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback please.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are using raw SQL queries instead of Django ORM calls and this causes portability issues when you switch database engines. I'd strongly suggest to use ORM if it's possible in your case. If not, then I'd say that you need to detect database engine on your own and construct queries depending on current engine.

In this case you could try to use `0` instead of `false`, I guess this should work both on SQLite and Postgres.

Comment: Sorry, Django is making all of the SQL queries there are no raw queries here.  Everything is already ORM based from the models.  The error is in the django base code.

Comment: I'm actually relieved to hear that ;) So let's dig deeper - how did you created tables then? Maybe you have taken SQL that created database in SQLlite and executed this on Postgres ? I's a wild guess, but this column should be bool, not int if was created using django management commands...

Comment: Well since everything is model based I just tell Django what database type to use in the settings.py application.  The only change I did was use Heroku's recommended database settings instead of the Django sqlite settings.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer my question. Can you please tell me/us how exactly did you created tables? Did you used Django management commands on Heroku, or did you connected to database directly and executed arbitrary SQL taken from SQLite schema?  It would also be useful if you could provide `DATABASES` setting from `settings.py` and content of `requirements.txt` - maybe you're using some weird postgress connector that doesn't do proper value conversion (which happen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606586/django-incorrect-integer-value-true-for-column-is-superuser-at-row-1)).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while executing raw sql queries in django but got it resolved by just using True|False to cast boolean expressions instead of 0|1.

Query code block is written below which executes perfectly in django.

```
cursor.execute(
   "insert into userapi_user(email,username,first_name,last_name,mobile_number,password,is_superuser,is_staff,is_active,date_joined)"
    "values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,False,False,True,%s)",
    (email, username, first_name, last_name, mobile_number, password, date)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is caused by a variable trying to change data types (i.e. from a char field to date-time) in the migration files.  A database like PostgreSQL might not know how to change the variable type.

So, make sure the variable has the same type in all migrations.

Comment: i forgot to mention.  special thanks to apollo13 on #django for figuring this out.